# Проблемы с VPN соединением Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Проблема следующая, у меня в общаге доступен только интернет предоставляемый университетом и подключиться к нему можно только через vpn, на windows все работает хорошо, а на ubuntu никак не хочет устанавливаться соединение.
Я создаю новое соединение через Network Manager:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом прописываю логин, который мне выдали в универе и имя сервера, пароль опускаю, чтобы ввести при выполнении подключения, вычитал в гугле что иначе вообще работать не будет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доп настройки такие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате при подключении получаю сообщение что соединение разорвано, т.к. vpn служба была остановлена.
Вот логи, пробовал устанавливать соединение с подключенным wifi(раздавал с телефона) и без, инфа в логах при этом разная, но понять что не так самому не получается.
Без wifi:

```
    Nov 25 17:24:11 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141451.2162] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f" name="VPN_TSU" pid=2062 uid=1000 result="success"
Nov 25 17:24:11 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141451.2207] vpn-connection[0x237b270,eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 5227
Nov 25 17:24:11 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141451.2294] vpn-connection[0x237b270,eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Nov 25 17:24:11 dicobi gnome-session[1852]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Nov 25 17:24:18 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141458.8835] keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VPN_TSU (eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU")
Nov 25 17:24:18 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141458.8918] vpn-connection[0x237b270,eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Nov 25 17:24:18 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <warn>  [1543141458.8958] vpn-connection[0x237b270,eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'не удалось найти IP-адрес шлюза PPTP VPN «vpdn.tsu.ru» (-3)'
Nov 25 17:24:18 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141458.8974] vpn-connection[0x237b270,eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Nov 25 17:24:18 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141458.8985] vpn-connection[0x237b270,eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU",0]: VPN service disappeared
```

С wifi:

```
Nov 25 17:26:43 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141603.4339] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f" name="VPN_TSU" pid=2062 uid=1000 result="success"
Nov 25 17:26:43 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141603.4380] vpn-connection[0x237b270,eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 5400
Nov 25 17:26:43 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141603.4467] vpn-connection[0x237b270,eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Nov 25 17:26:43 dicobi gnome-session[1852]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141609.4287] keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VPN_TSU (eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU")
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141609.4378] vpn-connection[0x237b270,eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: pppd started with pid 5417
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141609.4489] vpn-connection[0x237b270,eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi pppd[5417]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (plugin_init): initializing
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi pppd[5417]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 3 / phase 'serial connection'
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi pppd[5417]: Using interface ppp0
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: Using interface ppp0
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/7
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 5 / phase 'establish'
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi pppd[5417]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/7
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141609.4602] manager: (ppp0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/12)
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi pptp[5423]: nm-pptp-service-5400 log[main:pptp.c:350]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141609.4697] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141609.4706] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi pptp[5435]: nm-pptp-service-5400 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:259]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi pptp[5435]: nm-pptp-service-5400 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:781]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Nov 25 17:26:49 dicobi pptp[5435]: nm-pptp-service-5400 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:815]: Client connection established.
Nov 25 17:26:50 dicobi pptp[5435]: nm-pptp-service-5400 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:259]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Nov 25 17:26:50 dicobi pptp[5435]: nm-pptp-service-5400 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:900]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Nov 25 17:26:50 dicobi pptp[5435]: nm-pptp-service-5400 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:939]: Outgoing call established (call ID 10129, peer's call ID 17426).
Nov 25 17:26:50 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 6 / phase 'authenticate'
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (get_credentials): passwd-hook, requesting credentials...
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (get_credentials): got credentials from NetworkManager-pptp
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi pppd[5417]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 8 / phase 'network'
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi pppd[5417]: MPPE required but peer negotiation failed
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: MPPE required but peer negotiation failed
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 10 / phase 'terminate'
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 5 / phase 'establish'
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 11 / phase 'disconnect'
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: Connection terminated.
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi pppd[5417]: Connection terminated.
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: Terminated ppp daemon with PID 5417.
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <warn>  [1543141611.5554] vpn-connection[0x237b270,eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141611.5555] vpn-connection[0x237b270,eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <error> [1543141611.5568] platform-linux: do-change-link[13]: failure changing link: failure 19 (Нет такого устройства)
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <warn>  [1543141611.5568] device (ppp0): failed to disable userspace IPv6LL address handling
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141611.5575] vpn-connection[0x237b270,eb5caaec-41f0-44a8-b35d-70f7f7622e5f,"VPN_TSU",0]: VPN service disappeared
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1543141611.5653] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 1 / phase 'dead'
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: Child process /usr/sbin/pptp 82.200.70.12 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-5400 (pid 5420) terminated with signal 15
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi NetworkManager[936]: ** Message: nm-pptp-ppp-plugin: (nm_exit_notify): cleaning up
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi pppd[5417]: Child process /usr/sbin/pptp 82.200.70.12 --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-5400 (pid 5420) terminated with signal 15
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi pppd[5417]: Exit.
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi pptp[5423]: nm-pptp-service-5400 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:220]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi pptp[5423]: nm-pptp-service-5400 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:232]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi pptp[5435]: nm-pptp-service-5400 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:245]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi pptp[5435]: nm-pptp-service-5400 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:259]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Nov 25 17:26:51 dicobi pptp[5435]: nm-pptp-service-5400 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:84]: Closing connection (call state)
```

Comment: *pppd[5417]: MPPE required but peer negotiation failed* — перевод: мы требуем использование mppe, но вторая сторона отказывается.

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему следующим образом, в настройках обычного проводного соединения Ethernet во вкладке "параметры ipv6" во вкладке "способ настройки" поставил "игнорировать"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и в доп настройках pptp отключил MPPE шифрование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно закрывать вопрос

Answer (score 0):

В первом логе скорей всего ошибка dns, неправильный хост. Вероятно он должен называтся vpn.tsu.ru

Comment: Нет, все верно, хост именно такой